# EXP function codes with recursion function

Tags: c

I am trying to make exp function and i think that the algorithmic is true but i tried so many time to change the codes but it still not working .
    [image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

double faktoriyel(double x,double N)    ;

int main(){
double N,x,a;
double s=0;     
scanf("%lf", &x);
scanf("%lf",&N );
a=N; 
do 
{
s+=faktoriyel(N,x);
--a;   
}while (a>0);
printf("\n%lf\n",s) ;
}
double faktoriyel(double N,double x) 
{
if (N < 0)
return -1;
else if (N <2)
return pow(x,N)/1;
else
return (pow(x,N)/N * faktoriyel(N-1,x));
}
```

Comment: x^2/1! ---> x^2/2!

Comment: This is tagged C++ so you can just use `std::exp`. Now that I think about it, C should have the same function.

Comment: Last return, decomposition of X^N/N! gives X^N/N * ???

Comment: I wrongly tagged c++ i want to have a correction to my code in c not c++ and i cant use Prepared function i have to write the exp function with my codes

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/buciUg)

Comment: Now, that BLUEPIXY posted the solution you can start implementing argument reduction for `x>1` (haven't checked, but `x=2` is already too much off). Simplest method for argument reduction is by dividing by `1/(2^m)` where `m` depends on radix-size and absolute size. The formula to compute `m` is not very exact (made for arbitrary precision), just try some values `>64`. Reverse reduction for result `r` by recursively computing `r = 2r+r^2` `m` times.

Comment: Thanks  for help! @deamentiaemundi ,, i appreciate your effort in answering me but my English isn't so good and i am still beginner in c so can rewrite in a simpler way

Comment: i changed the last part like this what should i also do                                 double faktoriyel(double N,double x) 
{
if (N < 0)
return -1;
else if (N <2)
return pow(x,N)/1;
else if (x>1)
return (pow(x,N)/N * faktoriyel(N-1,x));

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing sums `x^N/k!`. You want to sum up `x^k/k!`. Simply change the the function call to `factoriyel(x,a)`

Comment: Confusing declaration/implementation of `factoriyel` isn't it?

Comment: He also seems to be doing `pow(x, N*(N+1)/2)` (if you expand the recursion)

Comment: you understanded  that i am trying to sums x^N/k! , in the funcation i calculated x^N/k!  and in main i inserted it in a do while loop to find the sum between 0 and N ,

Comment: I also chang the function calling as you said but it did n't give the tru answer